# How to create a confirmation dialog for call function

Tags: java, android, xml, dialog, phone-call

I am using eclipse for Android app development and i want to create a dialog box for confirmation when the call function is triggered from a button/s of the application.

For example when i press the button call i want a dialog box Are you sure you want to proceed? with yes and no.

As it is now when i press button for call it's auto dialing directly (no dial pad)

(I am not sure if this code is responsible for this)

```
public class AlertDialogManager {
/**
 * Function to display simple Alert Dialog
 * @param context - application context
 * @param title - alert dialog title
 * @param message - alert message
 * @param status - success/failure (used to set icon)
 *               - pass null if you don't want icon
 * */
public void showAlertDialog(Context context, String title, String message,
        Boolean status) {
    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();

    alertDialog.setTitle("Title");
    alertDialog.setMessage("Message");
    alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

}

Comment: Post your onClick of button code

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show the number in phone dial then just  do this `Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);`

```
public class AlertDialogManager {
/**
 * Function to display simple Alert Dialog
 * @param context - application context
 * @param title - alert dialog title
 * @param message - alert message
 * @param status - success/failure (used to set icon)
 *               - pass null if you don't want icon
 * */
public void showAlertDialog(Context context, String title, String message,
        Boolean status) {
    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();

    alertDialog.setTitle("Title");
    alertDialog.setMessage("Message");
    alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
          makeCall("12345");  //phone number you want to dial

        }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
    alertDialog.show();
}

private void makeCall(String phone){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+phone));
    startActivity(intent);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly you should implement something like this:

```
public void btnClick(View v) {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to proceed?");
    builder.setCancelable(false);

    builder.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            callFunction(); // THE FUNCT THAT YOU WANNA CALL
        }
    });

    builder.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    builder.show();
 }`
```